# Keyboard hover my EditText

Tags: java, android, layout, keyboard

here is my problem:

I want that my layout scroll and the bottom is above the keyboard, here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/MyLinearLyout_Zoom_all"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Contact_name_Zoom"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Contact"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/conv_zoom_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MyLinearLyout_Zoom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:hint="Write your message here" />

    <Button
        android:text="send"
        android:id="@+id/btn_send_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I've already tried the line: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" In my manifest

Comment: You need to be more clear-  what do you want to happen, what is actually happening.  Right now, we can't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I included pictures

Answer (score 0):

[Before the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwgaO.jpg)

[With the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ANES.jpg)